# What is the maximum value for the index_length of a MySQL 5.5 table?

Tags: mysql, index, mysql-5.5

I'm trying to find out why a series of inserts is painfully slow (1 minute 15 seconds, on average) on a dedicated MySQL 5.5.47 server, while the same inserts are normally fast (less than 5 seconds) on a Docker test server with MySQL 5.5.46. Storage engine is InnoDB on all relevant tables.

While comparing the characteristics of the tables involved, I noticed that, on the server where it's so slow, the following query returns 65536 for index_length:

```
select table_name, engine, index_length
from information_schema.tables 
where table_schema = 'suspicious_table';
```

And 65536 = 2^16. Could it be that I've hit a MySQL limit? Is it possible to have indexes larger than 65536?

I'd be glad to provide a explain output if it could help, but the above mentioned "actions" involve a lot of inserts, not just one or two, and on MySQL 5.5 and earlier versions, *explain* only works for selects, not for inserts, updates, or deletes.